# JavaScript getElementAt() command only returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, object, return, element

I am using the CodeHS javaScript version. I am making a snake program. I am trying to call an element (SNAKEY) when I run into it to stop the program, however when I try

```
if(direction == NORTH) {
    if(elemTopRight == SNAKEY)
         {
            gameOver();
        } else if(elemTopLeft == SNAKEY) {
            gameOver();
        } 
    }
```

(elemTopRight and elemTopLeft are getElementVariable)

it only returns [object Object] in my terminal.
Both my getElements and my SNAKEY element are global variables, but the getElementAt will not return SNAKEY when it runs into it. I need it to return the names of the elements when I run into them.

for the rest of the code context(no it is not pretty):

```
var elemTopRight = getElementAt(posX - 1, posY - 1);
var elemTopLeft = getElementAt(posX + 11, posY - 1);
var elemBottomRight = getElementAt(posX - 1, posY + 11);
var elemBottomLeft = getElementAt(posX + 11, posY + 11);
var elemCenterTop  = getElementAt(posX + 5, posY - 1);
var elemCenterBottom  = getElementAt(posX + 5, posY + 11);
var elemCenterRight  = getElementAt(posX + 11, posY + 5);
var elemCenterLeft  = getElementAt(posX - 1, posY + 5);
function checkCollision() {
elemTopLeft = getElementAt(posX - 1, posY - 1);
elemTopRight = getElementAt(posX + 11, posY - 1);
elemBottomLeft = getElementAt(posX - 1, posY + 11);
elemBottomRight = getElementAt(posX + 11, posY + 11);
elemCenterTop  = getElementAt(posX + 5, posY - 1);
elemCenterBottom  = getElementAt(posX + 5, posY + 11);
elemCenterRight  = getElementAt(posX + 11, posY + 5);
elemCenterLeft  = getElementAt(posX - 1, posY + 5);
if(direction == NORTH) {
    if(elemTopRight == SNAKEY)
         {
            gameOver();
        } else if(elemTopLeft == SNAKEY) {
            gameOver();
        } 
    }
    println(elemTopRight + ", " + elemTopLeft);
    if(direction == SOUTH) {
         if(elemBottomLeft != null && elemBottomLeft != food) {
            gameOver();
        } else if(elemBottomRight != null && elemBottomRight != food) {
            gameOver();
        }
    }
    if(direction == EAST) {
         if(elemBottomRight != null  &&  elemBottomRight != food) {
            gameOver();
        } else if(elemTopRight != null && elemTopRight != food) {
            gameOver();
        }
    }
    if(direction == WEST) {
         if(elemBottomLeft != null && elemBottomLeft != food) {
            gameOver();
        } else if(elemTopLeft != null && elemTopLeft != food) {
            gameOner();
    }

}
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var SNAKEY = new Rectangle(SNAKE_DIM, SNAKE_DIM);
function draw() {
checkCollision();
checkWalls();
SNAKEY = new Rectangle(SNAKE_DIM, SNAKE_DIM);
SNAKEY.setPosition(posX, posY);
SNAKEY.setColor(Color.green);
add(SNAKEY);
move();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cast an object to a string like in this line:

```
println(elemTopRight + ", " + elemTopLeft);
```

it will return [object Object]

`elemTopRight` is an object with variables. (propably X and Y) 
Use a different way to log its content.

like: `console.log(elemTopRight)`

Comment: The problem though is that is returns [object Object] for one element. if I `println(elemTopRight + ", " elemBottomRight)` then it will return [object Object], [object Object]

Comment: It will also not render the object as "food". It will only return null or object Object.

Comment: `object.toString()` returns `[object Object]`. If you chain those by `+ ", " +` you therefore get `[object Object], [object Object]`. You may try `println(JSON.stringify(elemTopRight))`.

Comment: So it returned the shape characteristics, which is good, but I would like it to return the name of the element. I cannot use getElementByName either.